# Forcing SSL on main domain files but not on files inside any folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am new in the web development & just bought SSL certificate and searched a lot to force domain to SSL & this is my working .htaccess code

```
#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I am trying to force to SSL without www on all files of the main domain but not the files inside any folder/directory of that domain

Eg:
if any one open

```
domain.com or www.domain.com force to -> https://domain.com
```

which is working by the above code BUT
I'm trying to force files under root dir of domain.com
Like these are the examples which will clear everything

```
domain.com/abc.php --> https://domain.com/abc.php
www.domain.com/def.php --> https://domain.com/def.php
domain.com/abc/xyz.php --> http://domain.com/abc/xyz.php
www.domain.com/abc/xyz.php --> http://domain.com/abc/xyz.php
https://domain.com/abc/xyz.php --> http://domain.com/abc/xyz.php
https://www.domain.com/abc/xyz.php --> http://domain.com/abc/xyz.php
```

in short i/m trying to force every files in root dir of domain to NON-WWW HTTPS.
But any files under any directry of that domain should force to NON-WWW without SSL.

I tried every possible i unable to do so.
Even don't know this can be possible with .htaccess or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule ^(.+/.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Not working in case if someone on https its not forcing to http.
But if anyone access without https its working.

Comment: @User2890725 okay, i added a rule for the https, see the edit